# Footer and container inside each other when I'm on small sized screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've created a login page, everything seems normal when the page is maximized but when I'm on xs and sm sized screen my footer and content area goes inside of each other and there's a gap at the bottom how may I solve this problem?

https://jsfiddle.net/tLhy3av1/

Full Code:

```css
.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-color: #E7E7E7;
  font-family: gesta;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.container.top {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.navbar-header.topHeader {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
.mid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 497px;
  background-color: #F1F2F4;
  margin-top: 110px
}
.myFooter {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #2F2F2F;
  border-top: 2px inset #F1F2F4;
}
.formSignIn {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 60px auto 30px auto;
}
.form-signin-heading {
  color: #8F95A3;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.btn {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  background-color: #F04B14;
  border: 1px solid #CE3D0D;
  background-color: #f04b14;
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #CE3D0D inset;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #F04B14;
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #CE3D0D inset;
  border: 1px solid #CE3D0D;
  background-color: #F47E57;
}
.forget {
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: right;
}
a {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #2693CE;
}
a:hover {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #2693CE;
}
.checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
}
.formSignIn p {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
#name {
  text-align: center;
  color: #8F95A3;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: 400px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
#bottomLinks a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #8F95A3;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: 400px;
}
#bottomLinks a:hover,
bottomLinks a:focus,
bottomLinks a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #535865;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: 400px;
}
.break {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container top">
      <div class="navbar-header topHeader">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Logo</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container mid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

        <form class="form-signin formSignIn">
          <h4 class="form-signin-heading">Log in</h4>
          <br>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
              <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
              <br>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
              <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
              <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
              <br>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">Remember me
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="forget">
                <a href="">Forgot password?</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
              <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log in</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
              <p>Not a member yet? <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"> Sign Up</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
              <p id="name">© Biz Yapalım <span id="bottomLinks"> <a href="http:/www.google.com">Privacy</a> <a href="http://www.google.com"> Terms</a></span> 
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class "break">
  </div>

  <footer class="container myFooter">

  </footer>
  <!--Javascript-->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your form set `width` to `px` or some other fixed value since percentage is from the width of a window and will always be a trouble:

```
.formSignIn {
    width: 200px; // 25%
}
```

Beside that, since you are covering more resolutions set some properties through media queries where you can stay with `%` value.